# For document served with Refresh HTTP header, why does w3 validator get empty source code?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, w3c-validation

I'm trying to check a website via [w3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&showoutline=yes&showimagereport=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fteenagewasterecs.com), but it always fails with this error:

> End of file seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

It's seems that it fails getting source code of the website for some reason.

However, if I add Accept-Language parameter (check [this request](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&showoutline=yes&showimagereport=yes&useragent=Validator.nu%2FLV%20http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices&acceptlanguage=ru_Ru&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fteenagewasterecs.com)), it will validate correctly. 
It's not only problem with w3 validator, for example, facebook parser, responsible for showing website preview, also doesn't see the source code.

The website uses Codeigniter php framework. Could it be the problem?
Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://teenagewasterecs.com` is zero-byte no-content.

So there’s nothing there for the validator to check — no document; instead the response only has HTTP headers, one of which is a `Refresh: 0;url=http://en.teenagewasterecs.com/` header.

So browsers see that `Refresh` header, follow it and load  `http://en.teenagewasterecs.com/`.

But the validator doesn’t follow that `Refresh`, nor load that other URL. Instead the validator tries to load and check `http://teenagewasterecs.com`. But it’s empty; thus the validator error you see.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the website link which you are checking

```
http://en.teenagewasterecs.com/
```

shows a 404 page not found on this link. Try with other website links.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, it seems that it redirects you to "en" subdomain. Need to check, maybe it's the cause of the problem.